# Why isn't the textbox accepting any value?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am keeping the value(inserted by user) of a text box in a variable $no. But it is not showing anything when I write an echostatement. I don't understand why??

I believe I am not inserting the value properly. I would like some help.
Thank you.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
                 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
          <title>Attendence form</title>
       <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
       </head>
       <body>
       <form action = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post">
        <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Lecture No</th>
      <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <select name = "dept">
        <option value = "cse">CSE</option>
        <option value = "eee">EEE</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
       <select name = "year">
        <option value = "1st">1st</option>
        <option value = "2nd">2nd</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
       <select name = "course">
        <option value = "cse2200">CSE 2200</option>
        <option value = "cse2201">CSE 2201</option>
        <option value = "cse2213">CSE 2202</option>
        <option value = "eee2217">EEE 2217</option>
        <option value = "math2207">MATH 2207</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type = "text" name = "days" />
       </td>
      <td>
       <?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Take attendence" />
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type = "submit" name = "view" value = "View Attendence" />
      </td>
    
     </tr>
     </table>
     <hr />
     <table>
      <?php
       $year = $_POST['year'];
       $dept = $_POST['dept'];
       $course = $_POST['course'];
       $no = $_POST['days'];
       $date = date("Y/m/d");
       
       echo $days;
       if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_POST['calculate']) && !isset($_POST['view'])){ 
         if($year == '1st')
        $roll = 1400000;
       else if($year == '2nd')
        $roll = 1300000;
       
       if($dept == 'cse')
        $roll = $roll + 7000;
       else if($dept == 'eee')
        $roll = $roll + 3000;
       $i = 1;
       echo '<tr><th>Attendence Form:</th></tr>';
       while($i <= 10){
        $roll = $roll + 1;
        echo '<tr> <td> <input type = "checkbox" value = "'. $roll . '" name = "present[]">'.$roll.'</input> </td></tr>';
        $i++;
         }
       ?>
         <td>
       <input type = "submit" name = "calculate" value = "Calculate" />
      </td>
      <?php 
       }
       else if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'rankodatabase')
       or die('Error connecting database');
        foreach($_POST['present'] as $p){
         $query1 = "SELECT * FROM attendence WHERE roll = '$p' AND course = '$course'";
         $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
        or die('Error in select query1');
         $p_days = 0;
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
          $p_days++;
          echo 'roll'. $row['roll'] . ' course' . $row['course'] . ' date' . $row['date'] . ' percentage' . $row['percentage'] . '<br />';
         }
         
         echo 'Lecture' . $no;
         /*$percentage = ($p_days / $no_of_lecture) * 100;
         $query2 = "INSERT INTO attendence VALUES('$p', '$course', '$date', '$percentage')";
         $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
         or die('Error in insert query2'); */
        }
        //$query = "INSERT INTO attendence VALUES('"
       }
    
       ?>
     </table>
     </form>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Try putting it in a `<td>`  or something

Comment: I don't follow. Isn't <input type = "text" /> is already inside a <td>? are you suggesting sth else??

Comment: `echo '<td>Lecture' . $no . '</td>';`

Comment: Thanks but still not getting it!

Comment: check using what you got var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: IT shows NULL! - @ParthChavda

Comment: That is a surprise. `var_dump($_REQUEST)` should at least show *"array("*, whatever you submit or not.

Comment: Did you realise that you do `echo $days`, but have no such variable? You probably intended `echo $no`. Also note your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, that your calculate button is in a `td` that has no `tr` as parent, and that `input` should not have a closing tag.

Comment: Thanks @trincot that was helpful really. But I don't understand one thing - that you said about the closing tag thing.

Comment: @user3805080 in HTML the `input` tag does not have a closing tag. It uses the `value` attribute to set or collect the text. Example: `<tr> <td> <input type = "checkbox" value = "4" name = "present[]" /></td></tr>`